# How does the Firebase help on firing tags in google tag management

Tags: firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics, google-datalayer

I am trying to understand what is the role of firebase to the google tag management.

According to the GTM document [Log events and variables](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/#log-events-and-variables), "your Firebase Analytics implementation acts as your data layer".

And in the **Fire tags** section, the document mentions "Trigger conditions are evaluated whenever you log a Firebase event".

My question is how this "DataLayer" Firebase Analytics triggers the other tags. Are those tags triggered by the Firebase server outside users' apps?

Or the Firebase Analytics is totally irrelevant to Tags in the Google tag management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Tag Manager's (GTM) mobile SDK relies on events from Firebase Analytics. Firebase Analytics provides some [Automatically Collected Events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485) that will be available for use as triggers in when firing tags.

You are also able to log custom events with the firebase analytics API. You can find more in the [developer center documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) (Android specific docs for logging events can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events)). Any events logged with Firebase Analytics are available for use as triggers within GTM. When those events are logged from within the application GTM will fire tags with corresponding triggers.