# How to connect new firebase project to existing Google Analytics (instead of creating a new GA Property)

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have an existing android app that is using Firebase & Google Analytics. This is **version 1**. It's working and I can see analytics data in Firebase & GA.

I'm working on **version 2** and trying to connect it to the existing Google Analytics acct. Is this possible?

It seems GA has changed their setup since a year+ ago and it is [suggesting for me](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317479?hl=en&ref_topic=6317493) to create a new property in GA, select 'mobile app', then connect to the firebase project. BUT I don't want to create a new property -- I don't want to lose the old data and would like to have it continuous.

Do I have to create a new account and lose the existing data?
Or can I just plug in the Google Analytics number somewhere in Version 2 (I can't find a place for that).

Answer (score 0):

The only way available as of today is to intercept [Firebase events via GTM](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/) and channel it to Google Analytics.

Checkout the first point of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984675/firebase-analytics-gtm-tracking/45987038#45987038) answer.

Comment: so the alternative is to just create a new GA acct then and start over right? Is there any other benefits of doing this other than being able to instantly connect to the firebase acct?

Comment: Were you able to link an existing property?